# How do I selectively run cpython's regression tests?

Tags: python-3.x, cpython

How do I run CPython3.3's own regression tests?

```
python3.3 -m test.regrtest packaging.tests.test_command_install_data
```

raises `ImportError: No module named 'test.packaging'`

Comment: From the [development guide](http://docs.python.org/devguide/runtests.html), something like this: `./python -m test -v test_abc`

Answer (score 2):

```
python3 -m test.regrtest
```

The command has options, and "python3 -m regrtest --help" shows extensive help. One thing you can do is add the names of specific test modules to the command-line, the names should be modules in the 'test' package. As an example, "python3 -m test.regrtest test_socket" runs the tests in the module "test.test_socket".

There are two problems with the the command line you're using:

1. You try to run tests that aren't in the test package, but in some other toplevel package
2. The toplevel package 'packaging' is not part of the stdlib for Python 3.3 (or any other
   version of Python)